# Highcharts pdf to have exactly same width and height as in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hello everyone I have a problem. I want that highcharts pdf has the same width and height as the highcharts, I set the sourceWidth and sourceHeight options of chart.exportChart() exactly the same to the chart.width and chart.height and exporting.scale = 1. but when I download the pdf it seems like the chart in pdf is a bit smaller than it is showing in the div.
I've created this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmtsbpea/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, '#FFFFFF'],
                [1, '#E0E0E0']
            ]
        },
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        scale: 1
    }
});

// the button handler
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChart( {type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: 'chart-pdf',
    sourceWidth: 500,
    sourceHeight: 400 });
});
```

});

please download and see that the pdf chart and chart in this fiddle are little different in width and height

Comment: You can define width/height of chart by [options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.sourceHeight), so extract these values from container width/height and push there.

Comment: ok I've done that too. in this : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h0vq36t/) but nothing is changed :(

Comment: Thank you for feedback, it looks like a bug, which is reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3982)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the Zoom Level in PDF.

Comment: @Yasemin if I remove exporting {scale:1} then it is giving me two times bigger than the actual width and height which is default value for "scale".

Answer (score -1):

You want that highcharts pdf has the same width and height as the highcharts, remove `"exporting {scale:1}"`.when this removed highcharts pdf has same width and hight with highcharts.Button handler part replaced with this

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    // the button handler
    $('#button').click(function () {
        chart.exportChart( {type: 'application/pdf' });
});
```